# Re-run an application script when it crashes?

Tags: bash, scripts

I have some applications that need to run on my laptop all the time.

I use a bash script to start these applications. In my script I have a loop that looks similar to this:

```
while true;
do
    xterm
done
```

This runs an application (`xterm` in this case) and if the application crashes, the loop starts it again.

This has a disadvantage that there is no "clean" exit from this loop. So even if the intention of the user is to close `xterm`, the loop starts it again.

Is there a way **to start** an application from bash script, watch whether it is running, **to re-run** it if script crashed or **do nothing** if the user closed it properly ?

Answer (score 47):

Try this:

```
while true; do xterm && break; done
```

Applications have [exit status codes](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html) so that if something exits fine it returns zero... And if something went wrong, it throws out another number. This allows people to hook in and find out the exact issue. This is what the other answer is doing.

`&&` just checks that the previous command was a zero-status exit and if it was, breaks the loop. If it crashes, it'll throw out something other than 0 and the `&& ...` clause won't trigger; it'll simply loop back around and run `xterm`.

Comment: That's quite elegant.

Comment: Hmm.. The other way around as well: `while xterm; do true; done`

Comment: @muru: This works for me: `while ! xterm; do :; done`

Comment: @Cyrus Ah, yes. forgot the `!`.

Comment: I've created a monster. How do I kill it?

Comment: In response to the follow-up question from @Tony Ruth: "I've created a monster. How do I kill it?": You can attach to the process using gdb and its process id: `sudo gdb -p <pid>`. Then from within GDB, run `call exit(0)` and the process will exit with status 0. Not the most elegant, maybe, but it'll get you out.

Answer (score 9):

In the `while` condition you can test whether exit status of `xterm` was successful or not with something like this:

```
result=1
while [ $result -ne 0 ]; do
    xterm
    result=$?
done
```

`$?` variable holds exit status of last executed command.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use.

```
until xterm ;  do  echo "program ended with status $?" ; done
```

This will re-run your program if it is killed.

Answer (score 0):

Try use [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) it very simple and easy to [add program or script to run](http://supervisord.org/running.html#adding-a-program). In you case as minimal you need `command` and maybe `exitcodes` in [programx-section](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#programx-section) to configure.

Default `exitcodes` is 0,2 so it means:

> supervisord will restart the process if it exits with an exit code that is not defined in this list

In general it`s that you want: *re-run* it if script crashed or *do nothing* if the user closed it properly(or script completed successfuly)

try the simplest configuration first:

```
[program:you_app_name]
command=/path/to/you/app
```

To more flexibility see [configuration File](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html) documentation.